# estimating how long a delete statement should take in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

```
DELETE table2
FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1
   ON table2.CITY = table1.CITY
WHERE table1.COUNTRY = 'Russia'
```

both tables have about half a million records, about 10 columns each. each column is not larger than about 100 characters

how long will this take if there are about 250,000 records matching the criteria?

Comment: Totally depends on your server, hard disk configuration, mySQL server configuration, RAM speed, hard disk bus type and speed... Why do you need to know this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your index configuration (if you have a lot of indexes, it will slow the query down A LOT), you MAY be faster doing:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_table2 LIKE table2;
ALTER TABLE tmp_table2 DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO tmp_table2 SELECT t2.* FROM table2 AS t2 JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t1.CITY = t2.CITY WHERE t1.country != 'Russia';
ALTER TABLE tmp_table2 ENABLE KEYS;
DROP TABLE table2;
RENAME TABLE tmp_table2 TO table2;
```

Basically, it creates a new table, tells it not to update indexes, inserts the "good" records, tells it to update the indexes, and then renames it...

NOTE:  Don't try to wrap this in a transaction, it won't work due to the DDL...